# Add multiple columns to a Pandas dataframe quickly

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing some performance-sensitive code in which I have to add a large number of columns to a Pandas dataframe quickly.

I've managed to get a 3x improvement over naively repeating `df[foo] = bar` by constructing a second dataframe from a dict and concatenating them:

```
def mkdf1(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10,20), columns=list('qwertyuiop'))
    for i in xrange(n):
        df['col%d' % i] = range(i, 10+i)
    return df

def mkdf2(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10,20), columns=list('qwertyuiop'))
    newcols = {}
    for i in xrange(n):
        newcols['col%d' % i] = range(i, 10+i)
    return pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(newcols, index=df.index)], axis=1)
```

The timings show substantial improvement:

```
%timeit -r 1 mkdf1(100)
100 loops, best of 1: 16.6 ms per loop

%timeit -r 1 mkdf2(100)
100 loops, best of 1: 5.5 ms per loop
```

Are there any other optimizations I can make here?

EDIT: Also, the `concat` call is taking much longer in my real code than my toy example; in particular the `get_result` function takes a lot longer despite the production df having fewer rows and I can't figure out why. Any advice on how to speed this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little confused at exactly what your dataframe should look like, but it's easy to speed this up a lot with a general technique.  Basically for pandas/numpy speed you want to avoid `for` and any `concat/merge/join/append`, if possible.

Your best bet here is most likely to use `numpy` to create an array that will be the input to a dataframe and then name the columns however you like.  Both of these operations should be trivial as far as computation time.

Here's the numpy part, it looks like you already know how to construct column names.

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(  np.ones([10,100]).cumsum(axis=0) 
                     + np.ones([10,100]).cumsum(axis=1) )
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop
```

I think you are trying to make something like this?  (If not, just check out numpy if you aren't familiar with it, it has all sorts of array operations that should make it very easy to do whatever you are trying to do here).

```
In [63]: df.ix[:5,:10]
Out[63]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
1   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13
2   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
3   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
4   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
5   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
```

Comment: Huh. For some reason I had it in my head that DataFrames stored by column, not by block, so the df would have to chop up the numpy array and it wouldn't be faster. Anyway, thanks so much for explaining that!

Comment: Two short follow-up questions: 1) if I'm starting with a dataframe `df` already supplied to me, is it reasonable to construct a numpy array for the columns I want to add, and then concat that to `df.values` at the numpy level? Or should I create an entirely new numpy array, write `df.values` into it, and then write my new column into it?

Comment: 2) if I have a mixed-type dataframe, will this still work (with a numpy array with `dtype=object`)? Or does Pandas do weird things with mixed types that would cause this to slow down?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any general advice for (1) or (2) but I also don't see any problems with what you are planning to do.  Honestly, I just go for simple and readable solutions first.  If those are too slow, then try alternate ways and post specific performance problems here.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, note that pandas is built on top of numpy so they generally get along very well.  You can often do stuff like a+b where a is a dataframe and b is a numpy array, without even thinking about it or pre-converting.

Comment: This also works for text. I have to build a giant dataframe containing only text column-by-column. Using a NumPy array with dtype=str or unicode worked 10x faster than pd.concat(). Thanks!